# Поиск почти равных значений элементов масива , поиск модуля значений масива

Tags: c++

Есть такой код , делает он следующее.
Пишет значения в вектор находя минимальное , максимальное значение ,
наименьшее из двух значений и равные значение.

```
int main()
{
    vector <int> item;

    double temp(0);
    double min(0);
    double max(0);

        setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
         cout << " " << endl;

          while (cin >> temp)   
             item.push_back(temp); // записываем значения в вектор.

          sort(item.begin(), item.end()); // сортируем вектор по возрастанию.

          for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); ++i) { // 

              cout << "[v." << i << "]" << item[i] << '\n';
              min = item[0]; // присваиваем первый элемент вектора ориентированным переменным.
              max = item[0];

              if (min > item[i]) // проверяем минимум.
                  min = item[i];

                  if (max < item[i]) // проверяем максимум.
                      max = item[i];
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); ++i) {
              for (int j = i + 1; j < item.size(); ++j) { // перебераем вектор начиная с первого +1 элемента.
                  if (item[i] == item[j]) { // проверяем на равенство элементы.
                      cout << " repyt int: "
                          << item[i] << " and " << item[j] << endl;
                  }
              }
          }

          cout << " lower value " << min //наименьшее значение.
               << endl
               << " the lesser of the two " << min << endl // наименьшее из двух значений.
               << " the largest value " << max // наибольшее значени.
               << endl;
}
```

Нужно этот код настроить так , чтобы в значениях массива находились почти равные друг другу значения и если они отличаются друг от друга меньше чем `1.0/10000000` то сначала нужно вывести меньше число , затем большее.
Не до конца понимаю как это работает.
Как я понял , что нужно взять модуль каждого элемента и сравнить с константами 1.0 и 10000000 или же записать так: `abs(a) -abs(b) < 1.0/10000000`.

Comment: Вычисляем погрешность `const double eps = 1.0 / 10000000;` и сравниваем два значения с полученной погрешностью `std::abs(a - b) < eps`

Comment: @its_space  У вас вектор целых чисел. Поэтому данное вычисление равных друг другу значений с десятичной погрешностью не имеет смысла. Кроме того не понятно, зачем вы сортируете вектор, а затем последовательно ищите минимальный и максимальный элементы.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow я просто показал код который нужно настроить для определённой задачи , так то естественно нужен вещественный тип данных.
Если вы объясните как искать мин и макс без сортировки , буду очень признателен вам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, чтобы найти минимальное и максимальное значения помещать числа в вектор не обязательно, это можно делать "на лету":

```
#include <limits>
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream>

// ...

double min  = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
double max  = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
std::vector<double> numbers();

{
    double temp = 0;
    while(std::cin >> temp)
    {
        min = std::min(min , temp);
        max = std::max(temp, max );

        numbers.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

Во-вторых, для поиска пар не требуется сортировать массив, вы же и так каждый с каждым сравниваете:

```
const double TOLERANCE = 0.00000001;

for(size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
{
    double a = numbers[i];

    for(size_t j = i + 1; j < numbers.size(); ++j)
    {
        double b = numbers[j];

        if(a == b)
        {
            std::count << i << " and " << j << " are equals " << a << "\n";
        }
        else if(std::abs(a - b) <= TOLERANCE) // проверяем погрешность
        {
            std::count << i << " and " << j << "are aproximately [" 
                       << std::min(a,b) << " ; " << std::max(a,b) << "]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Проверка погрешности `std::abs(a - b) <= TOLERANCE` работает следующим образом. Сперва вычислятся фактическая погрешность между значениями `a - b`. Фактическая погрешность может быть отрицательным числом, поэтому необходимо получить ее абсолютное значение с помощью стандартной функции  [std::abs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs), далее она сравнивается с целевой погрешностью `TOLERANCE`. Ну и собственно, если фактическая погрешность меньше или равна целевой, то считаем что числа приблизительно равны.

Comment: спасибо за хороший ответ , но хотелось понять лучше строку
else if(std::abs(a - b) <= TOLERANCE) , как она работает

Comment: @its_space добавил про погрешность

Comment: всё получилось , спасибо , но теперь мне нужно подумать как вывести вещественное число и знаки после точки)

Comment: cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
    cout.width(10);
    cout.precision(10);
такой формат решит мою проблему?

Comment: я немного не пойму , если я  наберу два числа , первое 0,00000001 и 0,00000000 , то на выходе будет второе число , а первое игнорируется

Comment: @ Cerbo (abs(a - b) это мы получаем модуль чисел , например а = 4 , b = 5 , то модуль будет единица и эта единица сравнивается с константой , я правильно мыслю?

Comment: для общего понимания я взял значения в константе 0.2 , всё понятно , большое спасибо.